# Can't get firebug 1.7 to work in firefox 4 on a Mac

Tags: firefox, firebug, firefox4

I recently installed firebug 1.7 on firefox 4 ...

When I try to enable it in the Add-ons area I can, however I don't get the icon appearing in the bottom right corner of the browser window and in the Tools drop down it appears as firebug.Firebug minus any functionality. Screen shot:

[image]

Has anyone out there had a similar problem?

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this kind of problem using Firefox3 and Firefox4 alternately. That is to say, I have both versions installed and keep switching between them for development purposes.

It seems that you need to uninstall and then reinstall Firebug in the FF version that won't show the icon in the bottom corner.